# angular.js event emit, variable load time

Tags: angularjs

I have these 2 controllers:

```
app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.number = 0;

  $rootScope.$on('do', function(event, data) {
      $scope.number += data;
  });
}]);
app.controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  this.something = function() {
     $scope.$emit('do', 5);
  };
}]);
```

and in html I'm just writing this variable:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">{{number}}</div>
```

When I call `something` function it emits the `do`. But it's updating the number like 10 seconds. Why?

Comment: This is not the answer of your question, but using events for communicating with two Controllers is generally a bad practice.
You could either use a Service and $scope.$watch to manage communication, or use Directive if a Controller is a component inside of another.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at those things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by calling `$scope.$apply();`.